# how to total all row in page that was sql LIMIT

Tags: php

i put limit in this code but how can i calculate the **totalmin** in this page?

here is my code

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM time WHERE id = $id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>

<table border="0" style="width:50%">
<tr>
    <th>Time in</th>
    <th>Time Out</th>
  </tr>
<?php

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><center>".$row['totalmin']."</center></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
</table>

mysql_close();
```

i want to know how to total all the mins in 15 row with php code

Comment: Store `$row['totalmin']` then add it, or do you just want the sum? You aren't closing that `while` loop in this code and `</table>` will cause an error. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @JayBlanchard its not gonna use website im using for an assignment in school for now im considering mysql but later on ill study mysqli and PDO for the meantime i need to use mysql coz it was easiest way

Comment: @chris85 forgot to close the while sorry

Comment: I hate when people say *"I'm not that far along..."* or *"This site will not be public..."* or *"It's only for school, so security doesn't matter..."*. If teachers and professors are not talking about security from day one, they're doing it wrong. Challenge them. They're teaching sloppy and dangerous coding practices which students will have to unlearn later. I also hate it when folks say, *"I'll add security later..."*. If you don't have time to do it right the first time, when will you find the time to add it later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may do the trick, if you want to show sum only
But you should NOT use mysql_ functions, and this code is not sequre from SQL Injects

```
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM time WHERE id = $id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $sum = 0;
    $num = 0;
    ?>

    <table border="0" style="width:50%">
    <tr>
        <th>Time in</th>
        <th>Time Out</th>
      </tr>
    <?php

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $num++;
        $sum += $row['totalmin'];
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><center>".$row['totalmin']."</center></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        if($num == 15){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><center>".$sum."</center></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
    ?>
</table>

<?php 
mysql_close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store `$totalmin` into your while loop and update it with new value if `$row['totalmin']` is less then `$totalmin`.

Use something like this:

```
$totalmin = null;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (is_null($totalmin) || $row['totalmin'] < $totalmin) {
        $totalmin = $row['totalmin'];
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $totalmin . "</center></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: so it does limit into 15 row sir?

Comment: yes, because you get from database only this 15 rows. If you need overall totalmin over all rows you should use another sql query

Answer (score 0):

Sum up the minutes as you loop through the result:

```
$sum = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $sum += floatval($row['totalmin']); //or intval()
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><center>".$row['totalmin']."</center></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo $sum;
```

*make sure you close your while loop*